# UILabel with two lines weird behavior in UICollectionCell

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have some trouble with a CustomViewCell which has a `UILabel` which has two lines.

Everything is looking like expected if I first show my `CollectionView`. If `UILabel` has only one line, the title is at the top. However, if I start scrolling to the end of the list and than go back to top, all `UILabels` have two lines and sometimes the titles are divided in the middle like

BEFORE: AwesomeTitle

AFTER: Awesom

eTitle

I'm quit sure it has something to do with `reusable Cells`, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

I set the textLabel for the cell like:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyItem* a = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CustomSelectionView *bookCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CustomSelectionCell_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //CELL CONTAINS an UIImage (Cover) and two UILabels (Author, Title)

    //get image from storage
    NSString* isbn = a.isbn;
    NSString* filePath = [_mamPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", isbn]];

    FDIBookCollectionViewCell* __weak weakCell = bookCell;    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];

        if (!image) {
            //... handle
        }

        if (image && weakCell) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                weakCell.imageView.image = image;
                [weakCell.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
            });

        }

    });


    //set author and title
    bookCell.titelLabel.text = a.titel;

    bookCell.titelLabel.numberOfLines = 2;  //title label can have two lines
    [bookCell.titelLabel sizeToFit];

    return bookCell;
}
```

InterfaceBuilder for Cell:

[image]

BookCell.m

```
    @implementation FDIBookCollectionViewCell {}

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {

        }
        return self;
    }

    //...
    - (void)prepareForReuse {
        [super prepareForReuse];

        self.imageView.image = nil; 
    }

    @end
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, I think the issue is to do with when the cell is being prepared for reuse during scrolling. You're already setting the image to nil in `prepareForReuse` which is good, you should just have to set the label to nil there as well so your method becomes:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    self.imageView.image = nil;
    self.titelLabel = nil;   
}
```

Fingers crossed that should work!

EDIT:

In your custom cell header, define a setContent method and your label variables:

```
-(void)setContentWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)content;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titelLabel;
```

Then in your implementation file:

```
-(void)setContentWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)content
{
    //Initialise your labels here
    titelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    //Customise label and set text
    [titelLabel setText:[content valueForKey:@"CellTitle:]];
}
```

Then:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Most of your current code
    //Not tested this line, probably won't work as is but you get the idea!
    NSDictionary *cellContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithValuesAndKeys:[a.titel], @"CellTitle"];
    CustomSelectionView *bookCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CustomSelectionCell_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [bookCell setContent:cellContent];
    return bookCell;
}
```

For each other element on your cell, simply add a new element in the dictionary. This way, every time a cell needs to be drawn, it is getting the correct content and the labels will be set up in the correct way.

Hopefully this all makes sense and help!

Matt

Comment: setting titelLabel.text = nil; didn 't work, but setting the whole label to nil did it! thanks for pushing me into the right direction. i edited your answer and accept if i'm allowed

Comment: Glad I could help! I guess it depends how/when the object is being initialised. If you're referencing a label or other object in interface builder then you just need to set the text to nil. I guess in your case you're initialising everything in code? (Which is probably the better way, but thats a whole different topic!) In which case yes, you would want to set the whole label to nil ready for reinitialisation!

Comment: yeah. just realized that now sometimes the labels aren`t right any more.. any tips for that?

Comment: Aren't right how? How is the cell being defined and where are you initialising the label?

Comment: Can you please explain how the cells aren't right?
The issue might be that in prepareForReuse you are setting the cell to nil then I'm presuming it isn't getting reinitialised fully afterwards. I don't fully know what lifecycle your cells will have as I don't know if you're referencing from a storyboard or IB file, or if everything is created programatically. You just need to make sure when you give the cell the data, you pass the data and reinitialise everything. I'll add an edit to my answer that will help you do this.

Comment: problem solved! actually i guess my main problem was with callin the `[bookCell.titelLabel sizeToFit]`. guess with the combination of reuse and the problem with `UILabels` with multiple lines, I had some strange alignment. I switched to a `UITextView`, after that your solution worked well. thanks again!!!